# Is there a way to make a chart like this interactive?

Tags: reactjs, visualization

I'm thinking of an interactive way to specify the peak periods based on this chart here:
[image: https://www.oeb.ca/sites/default/files/chart_electricity_tou_1.jpg]

Basically to be able to cycle through off-peak (1st click), mid-peak (2nd click) and on-peak (3rd click) colors and specify the time range by dividing the chart into 24 pieces (like 24 hour).

https://gooduling.github.io/react-circular-timepicker/#/findpeople

Is there a closest react or bootstrap framework I can refer to? So far I can't seem to find a suitable template I could work on.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of amazing packages that I can recommend for charting:

- [DevExtreme](https://js.devexpress.com/Overview/Charts/) this one is suitable if you want to control every aspect of your chart. whether it regards animations, interactions or any other aspect
- [ReactCharts](https://react-charts.tanstack.com/examples/simple) the very famous tenstack react charts. I would go for this personally for 95% of my projects. it is east configurable but not like the dev extreme.

There are so many more options but I generally would pick between those 2 above